# Add month to quarter date

Tags: date, sas

I have two lines of code which determine the previous quarters start and end dates.

```
put(INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'B'),MMDDYY10.)
put(INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'E'),MMDDYY10.)
```

The Start date above shows as 10/1/2019
The End date above shows as 12/31/2019

However I need to add one month to each date to equal the below.

11/1/2019
1/31/2019

I tried nesting the above in another intnx function but it just returns blank. Thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you tried, in particular the 'nesting the above in another intnx function'. That is the correct approach.

Comment: @Reeza. Thank you for the input. I tried be the below.

INTNX('Month',put(INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'B'),MMDDYY10.),+1,'B');

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between a date value, a formatted date value and data that is the string representation of a date.  INTNX functions deal with date values, not their string representations (as would be caused by PUT)

Comment: That last bit about PUT got me to exactly where I needed. This works perfectly. Thank you everyone.
put(INTNX('Month',INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'B'),+1,'B'),MMDDYY10.);
put(INTNX('Month',INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'E'),+1,'E'),MMDDYY10.);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
data _null_;
   * compute date values;

    * start of second month in prior quarter;
    start_date = intnx('MONTH', intnx ('QUARTER', today(), -1, 'B'), 1);

    * end of first month after prior quarter;
    end_date   = intnx('MONTH', intnx ('QUARTER', today(), -1, 'E'), 1, 'E');

    * log date values using a desired representation format;

    put (start_date end_date) (=mmddyy10./);

    * store a date value representation in a variable;
    * (this is not typically a desired thing to do);

    start_ymd = put (start_date, mmddyy10.);
    end_ymd   = put (end_date,   mmddyy10.);

    * log the string values that were forced to represent a date (via PUT);

    put start_ymd= / end_ymd=;
run;
```

Log should show (on 6-jan-2020)

```
start_date=11/01/2019
end_date=01/31/2020
start_ymd=11/01/2019
end_ymd=01/31/2020
```

Answer (score 1):

The below works perfectly.

`put(INTNX('Month',INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'B'),+1,'B'),MMDDYY10.)`

`put(INTNX('Month',INTNX('Quarter',today(),-1,'E'),+1,'E'),MMDDYY10.)`

Comment: It shouldn't be +1, just 1. Your answer is correct, but unless you need a character date, I would recommend against using PUT in the conversion.